# What non-programming books should a programmer read to help develop programming/thinking skills?

Tags: self-improvement, books

There are a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170208/must-have-books-on-your-bookshelf) [of](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/870/if-you-could-only-have-one-programming-related-book-on-your-bookshelf-what-would) questions about what programming books should be on the programmer's bookshelf. How about non-programming related books that can help you become a better programmer or developer? It would also be interesting to know why they would help.

My first choice would be Sun Tzu's "Art of War" (however cliché), because it made it obvious that the success of any project depends on the strength of its weakest link (and warfare is a big project).

Comment: Joel Spolsky recommends a creative writing and economics courses for students. The reasoning being that it helps you communicate better (expressing ideas, writing docs) and understand the business behind the software you write. Maybe a book on each of those topics would be a good idea if you haven't taken these courses at university.

Comment: Does the [closed] mean that I have to save away this thread before it is removed, or will it stay here in a [closed] state? I really find this thread useful even if it does not meet all the quality standards of the (less formal than SO) programmers Q&A site.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[The Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465067107) by Donald Norman

[image]

Comment: Added to my reading list.

Answer (score 37):

Getting Things Done

David Allen

[image: Cover]

Comment: Sadly, I got this book 5-6 years ago and my bookmark is still somewhere in the middle of it.

Comment: It's funny. You need read the entire book to learn how to finish the book :-)

Comment: As for me, it could be much thiner. The same concepts are explained in this book over and over, which doesn't adds more value. But that's IMHO :)

Comment: I agree with Yan here, I personally think a lot of the chapters can be skimmed over and some need to read in detail.

Comment: Here is a good complement to the book: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo7vUdKTlhk

Answer (score 31):

[Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394756827) by [Douglas Hofstadter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Hofstadter).

If you haven't read this, put it on your list. It's still breathtaking over 30 years later. While [I am a Strange Loop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FA23HM) contains a more complete and convincing argument about where consciousness comes from, GEB explores the realms of symmetry, intelligence and logic systems through the music of Bach, the mathematics of Gödel and the art of Escher. It's as infuriating and entertaining as it sounds.

[image: Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid]

Comment: Hear, hear, fantastic book!

Comment: I know a lot of people speak highly of this book - but I found it extremely difficult to follow.

Comment: I found this book to be one of the most challenging books to read, but nonetheless a fantastic one.

Answer (score 27):

**[How to win friends and influence people](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439167346)**

As mentioned here: [What non-programming books should programmers read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210) "How to win friends and influence people" is a VERY good book.

*You don't acquire programming skills directly by this book, but indirectly I'll argue that you do.* If you're not very good at dealing with people this will help you with socializing with people that may influence you and your programming skills.

The title of the book may sound a little superficial but it´s not. You learn what others do naturally, and Dale Carnegie encourage you not to be superficial.

**Worth a read :-)**

[image: How to win friends and influence people]

Comment: Although the example scenarios are a little old now, the practical aspects of this book still hold today.

Comment: This is a book whose title gives entirely the wrong impression.  It sounds like it's about how to manipulate people.  In fact, it's about how to get along with people and inspire people by being a good, decent person.

Answer (score 25):

[Don't Make Me Think! A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789723107)

Relevant to all user interface design.

Also includes general common sense for design that every programmer should know.

[image: Don't Make me think]

Answer (score 21):

The Art of War
Sun Tzu

[image]

Comment: I wish I could vote more than once for this.

Comment: It's funny that this appears right after "How to Win Friends and Influence People"...  "If plan A fails, there's always plan B..."  :)

Comment: Same as Walter...

Answer (score 19):

Peopleware: Productive Projects and Teams
Tom DeMarco and Timothy Lister

[image]

Answer (score 16):

The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People
Stephen Covey

[image]

Comment: I'm reading this book and find it helpful in determining my priority in life.

Comment: I detested the 7HoHEP.  A friend once commented that the first habit of highly effective people was not wasting time reading books like this.  I get that others disagree but I found this about 50 pages of interesting (though sometimes obvious) material bulked up to justify a book.

Comment: -1 these kind of books put more pressure on us.

Comment: Although being a bit to "self-improvish", The "Sharpening the saw" principle is about the most important things you can learn as a programmer

Comment: Don't waste time reading this book.  Skim it or find a summary it's horribly bloated & repeats the same (self evident) point several times in slightly different ways.  Probably ideal for teaching time management to the hard-of-thinking

Answer (score 13):

Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance

Robert Pirsig

It teach us how to do right maintenance on software.

[image]

Comment: *"It teach us how to do right maintenance on software."* -- It's an interesting book, but it certainly didn't teach *me* anything about software. It's more like an introduction to philosophy.

Comment: @stakx: Exactly. Did you read the question? None books here is about software. It's good reading to help us to write better software. If a reader can't understand how it applies to software development...

Comment: This is a great book, and the follow up, "Lila" is just as good.  He sets out to create a new "metaphysics", and I think he failed to do that, but by the end of the book he *succeeds* at specifying an algorithm that codifies western values: given any two things, you can use his "metaphysics of quality" to figure out which one western society values more.  I think that's quite the accomplishment, though I'm not sure that's how he sees it.

Comment: Yep.  I have a quote from this book posted right above my monitor.

Answer (score 8):

[Predictably Irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictably_Irrational)

[image: Predictably Irrational]

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to recommend a triplet of books that are about being a programmer (rather than programming), or a leader of programmers. While all are over 30 years since their original publication all are (especially with updates, commentary in their anniversary editions):

- "[The Mythical Man Month](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201835959)", Brooks.
- "[Peopleware](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633439)", BeMarco & Lister.
- "[The Psychology of Computer Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633420)", Weinberg (the PL/1 code is easy to follow, and can easily be applied to edge cases of any programming language).

Comment: They are still all programming books. A programming book is not necessarily always about a specific language/technology.

Comment: @MAK, they are actually more about software management than about actual programming directly. They are classics that I strongly recommend to any if not every professional developer for becoming a more well rounded developer. I admit they are at the fuzzy _border_ of whether they are programming or non-programming books about development/software management.

Answer (score 6):

I would say any introductory book on graphic design would be useful for a programmer and help them while programming for some aspects of their work.

For example:

[The Non-Designer's Design Book: Design and Typographic Principles for the Visual Novice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1566091594)

[image]

Comment: Heh, I wouldn't be too keen on reading a book on design that had a cover with that colourscheme ;)

Answer (score 6):

[The Soul of a New Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soul_of_a_New_Machine)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

A Pattern Language: Towns, Buildings, Construction

It will teach you how to see that wildly disparate things can have underlying patterns in common that can be applied in an entirely different context. The aspect of a CEO's office that makes it a great office can be present in an undergrad's residence room, or missing from your million dollar mansion. Once you get this concept, you can apply it to software, as the Gang of Four did, and you will understand Design Patterns so much more completely. You will also have nicer living and working spaces for the rest of your life.

Comment: I've been very impressed by Alexander and Gabriel's writings on patterns and software, and, dually, disappointed by the "Object Oriented Design Patterns" movement.

Answer (score 6):

[Cryptonomicon](http://www.cryptonomicon.com/):

[image: Cryptonomicon Cover Art]

Recommended for the morale boost.  :)

Answer (score 5):

[The Back of the Napkin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0020MMBCG), by [Dan Roam](http://www.thebackofthenapkin.com/).

[The Back of the Napkin http://www.coverbrowser.com/image/bestsellers-2008/302-7.jpg](http://www.coverbrowser.com/image/bestsellers-2008/302-7.jpg)

A great book about visual thinking techniques.  There is also an [expanded](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591843065) edition now.  I can't speak to that version, as I do not own it; yet.

Comment: The expanded edition is the "director's cut" printed in 2-colors black + red) and with an added appendix (10 1/2 Commandments of Visual Thinking, which is a nice recap of things to keep in mind). There might be additional content, but I don't have the first edition so I can't contrast them.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody has suggested any fiction. I would have though reading some fiction every now and then would improve your thinking skills. Anyway, here's my 2c.

> The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
>   is a wholly remarkable book. Perhaps
>   the most remarkable, certainly the
>   most successful book ever to come out
>   of the great publishing corporations
>   of Ursa Minor - of which no Earthman
>   had ever heard of. More popular than
>   the Celestial Home Care Omnibus,
>   better selling than Fifty-Three More
>   Things to do in Zero Gravity, and more
>   controversial than Oolon Colluphid's
>   trilogy of philosophical blockbusters
>   Where God Went Wrong, Some More of
>   God's Greatest Mistakes and Who is
>   this God Person Anyway? It's already
>   supplanted the Encyclopedia Galactica
>   as the standard repository of all
>   knowledge and wisdom, for two
>   important reasons. First, it's
>   slightly cheaper; and secondly it has
>   the words **DON'T PANIC** printed in
>   large friendly letters on its cover.

Comment: I have to say that the BBC Radiophonic Workshop version of Hitchhikers is **absolutely awesome** - lots of amazing sound effects, so you are completely engrossed and feel like you are there with Ford, Zaphod, Arthur and Trillian, et al.

Comment: But quite silly :)  I love it though..

Comment: Lots of jokes in ICT refer to this book, especially jokes found in old source code.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very inspirational book on creativity.  Something sorely needed in this 'new' tech world full of 'best practices' and 'accepted methodologies'.

[image: Ignore Everybody]

Answer (score 4):

[Pragmatic Thinking And Learning](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pragmatic-Thinking-Learning-Refactor-Programmers/dp/1934356050/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1294904907&sr=8-1) by Andrew Hunt.

[image]

Though the targeted audience is programmers, non-programmers can read it as well. It just uses some programming metaphors. But the book is really about how the brain functions, and how we can optimize how we use it.

Answer (score 3):

"How to solve it" by George Pólya. While targeted for mathematics, the problem solving strategies can readily be applied to programming.

Answer (score 3):

[The Inmates are Running the Asylum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672316498) has been helpful to me during the planning stage of any software, or interaction project.

Answer (score 2):

Math Refresher for Scientists and Engineers

John R. Fanchi

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While [Strategy of the Dolphin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0449905292) is geared more towards adjusting one's mindset to solving problems arising from dealing with others, applying the adaptive skills in dealing with the absolute world of developer tools will help intuit new ways of addressing problems.

[image: Strategy of the Dolphin]

Answer (score 2):

The single best book on writing I've ever read is [*The Sense of Structure: Writing from the Reader's Perspective*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205296327).

[image: The Sense of Structure]

It can help you think logically about your writing. It gives concrete advise about the structure of what you say. It's not a book about grammar mistakes or rules, nor a bunch of platitudes-- which distinguishes itself from most other writing books. [At least that I've seen, and I've read "the classics" too.]

Better writing can help you compose better emails, write write clearer comments, and help you realize what you think it important or not.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Kings - On Writing,  No I'm serious so stick with me! :) I realized that the coding process actually have a lot in coming with the authoring process. First you need to get things  down on paper/code, then you need to edit/refactor it. You need to let the book/code "rest" a little sometimes before coming back to it with new realizations etc etc

Read the book and think about how it applies to coding

Answer (score 1):

[Made to Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1400064287) - Absolutely essential for building skills on getting your ideas across to others (especially non-programmers) and looking at things from others' (read customers') perspectives.

Answer (score 1):

[Patterns of Home](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1561585335)

[image: Patterns of Home front cover]

An excellent reference on 10 patterns for the *process* of designing homes. Instead of being a catalog of patterns for elements of a home (such as living room, alcove, patio, etc.), it's a catalog of principles that should shape the design of homes; a guide to the factors that are critical to making a home livable for its habitants.

I've translated the 10 design process patterns they catalog to the design of software and it's remarkable how effective they are in helping you focus on the details relevant to big-picture thinking before you get bogged down on the specifics of designing and coding classes.

Comment: Maybe it's not surprising, the book is probably inspired by the seminal work of Christopher Alexander  "A Pattern language", the guy who **invented** design patterns for use in architecture, the concept was later adopted by computerscience and the gang of four

Comment: Actually, two of the book's authors, Max Jacobson and Murray Silverstein, worked with Christopher Alexander (and others) to assemble those patterns.

But again, while APL focused on the patterns to be implemented in a residential structure, this book focuses on patterns for designing/judging a well-designed home. It gives remarkable insight into determining how to design a software system well, or if it was designed so.

Answer (score 1):

*Alice In Wonderland* and *Through The Looking-Glass*.  Read Alice's conversation with the White Knight and see if you don't come away with a deeper appreciation for indirection and reference variables!

Answer (score 1):

[Six thinking hats](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316178314)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The art of problem solving](http://books.google.com/books?id=2qu8EK7ickIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Russell+L.+Ackoff+the+art+of+problem+solving&source=bl&ots=Da0lC4iFCL&sig=8qJvEcpAImgeSVpFIc-ZCIuDCis&hl=en&ei=3v78TLCiA9HpOeyrlNUK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

[Dan Millman's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Millman) "Everyday Enlightenment". A self-help book, whose title is far more esoteric than the advice it actually gives. It is clearly written and structured, encouraging, and actually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Mind performance hacks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101538)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Conceptual Blockbusting** *by* James L. Adams

A good book concerning problem solving.

Answer (score -3):

- Code complete
- The Pragmatic Programmer

Comment: This are both programming books.